# Matlab - import files independent of header or none

Tags: matlab, data-structures

I want to import data files independent whether it has a header or not. The working examples are:

```
function PlotMyData(Datafile_with_header)
 data=importdata(Datafile_with_header);
 plot(data.data(:,1),data.data(:,2));
end
```

and

```
function PlotMyData(Datafile_without_header)
 data=importdata(Datafile_without_header);
 plot(data(:,1),data(:,2));
end
```

Let's say I want to write a function `PlotMyData('Datafile.dat')` which can plot the data independent of having a header or not. In fact I can not just apply the first routine because Matlab directly converts the data without header to a matrix.

Comment: Is there any way you can determine if a file has a header or not?

Comment: Yes you can read the files first line of the file whether it contains characters or not (as the rest contains only numbers)... But the data-files randomly contain a header or not. So there is no external feature to determine the "having-a-header" property.